# Add bullets to slider that automatically change with the right slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I made a slider with seven pictures and next and previous buttons. The slider works automatically and when hovering the slider the loop stops.

I've tried to add interactive bullets - now wrote in static HTML - that respond to their given picture.
The bullets should be as many as there are slides, but *without* having to add them myself one by one.
But I don't know how to do it. Can anyone help?

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1} 
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none"; 
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace("active", "");
  }

  if (slides.length > 0) { 
    slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
    dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  var interval = setInterval(function() {
    var $curr = $('.mySlides:visible'), 
        $next = ($curr.next().length) ? $curr.next() : $('.mySlides').first();
    $next.css('z-index',2).fadeIn('slow', function() {
      $curr.hide().css('z-index',0);
      $next.css('z-index',1);
    });
  }, 5000);
  
  $('.mySlides').hover(function() {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }, function() {
    interval = setInterval(function() {
      var $curr = $('.mySlides:visible'), 
          $next = ($curr.next().length) ? $curr.next() : $('.mySlides').first();
      $next.css('z-index',2).fadeIn('slow', function() {
        $curr.hide().css('z-index',0);
        $next.css('z-index',1);
      });
    }, 5000);
  });
});
```

```css
/* SLIDER*/
#containermio {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 536px;
  position: relative;
}

#containermio a:hover {
  color: white;
}

#containermio ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

#containermio ul li {
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
  position: relative;
}

#containermio ul li:first-child {
  display: block;
}

#containermio ul li img {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

/* FADE */
.mySlides {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

/* SLIDE TITLE*/
.text {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px 0 0 25px;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #f7f7f7;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

/* ARROWS */
.prev, .next {
  z-index: 99;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 40%;
  width: auto;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  padding: 25px 25px 25px 25px;
}

.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* DOTS */
.dotdiv {
  bottom: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 99;
}

.dot {
  cursor:pointer;
  height: 6px;
  width: 6px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #eee;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
  z-index: 99;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="containermio">
  <ul id="slidermio">
    <li class="mySlides">
      <div id="slide1" class="text">alicè</div>
      <img src="http://digitaljournal.com/img/8/7/8/4/4/i/1/1/7/o/ulingan_kids.jpg"/>
    </li>
    <li class="mySlides">
      <div id="slide2" class="text">halo halo</div>
      <img src="http://freethoughtblogs.com/taslima/files/2012/06/22-funny2.jpg"/>
    </li>
    <li class="mySlides">
      <div id="slide3" class="text">tilt</div>
      <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png"/>
    </li>
    <li class="mySlides">
      <div id="slide4" class="text">artist unknown</div>
      <img src="http://www.chinadaily.com.cn/china/images/2010WenUN/attachement/jpg/site1/20100921/0013729ece6b0e01d9691a.jpg"/>
    </li>
    <li class="mySlides">
      <div id="slide5" class="text">insa</div>
      <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz2.png"/>
    </li>
    <li class="mySlides">
      <div id="slide6" class="text">blue lights</div>
      <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz3.png"/>
    </li>
    <li class="mySlides">
      <div id="slide7" class="text">outdoor festival</div>
      <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz3.png"/>
    </li>
  </ul>
  
  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
  
  <div class="dotdiv">
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(+1)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(+1)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(+1)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(+1)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(+1)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(+1)"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e9m3yupp/**  *(original: https://jsfiddle.net/hctxgqhx/)*

Comment: Where is your `currentSlide` function?

Comment: I'm sorry I deleted it accidentally. I correct the code, anyway I past it here. @nashcheez

    function currentSlide(n) {
         showSlides(slideIndex = n);
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed a lot in your code, in order to make it much more flexible and concise.
There are too many changes to explain every single one, so I used comments in the code snippet below instead, to explain what every line does.

But I will sum up the most major changes:

- I put all the slides in an array. In that array, every slide is represented by an object containing a `txt` and an `img` property. The first index of the array (`[0]`) is used to store the slide-index.
  I removed the `<ul>` with all the `<li>`s from the HTML, and replaced them with one `<div>`. And instead of switching elements, I change the source of the image.
  *This way, you don't have to add new slides to your HTML, all you have to do is add a slide-object to the slides-array in JS.*
- I moved the `onclick` handlers (for the *arrows* and *bullets/dots*) from HTML to JS. It's considered good practice to keep all JS-code outside of your HTML.
- Don't pay too much attention to all the 'changes' in the CSS. Mostly, those are just me reordering and reformatting things for my own readability, but I'll admit it's an acquired taste:)
  *There might be however a few actual changes that are critical for proper layout/functionality, but like I said I changed so much that I don't even remember.*

Unfortunately, I couldn't get the CSS `fade` animation (see code block below) to work with the new code. Because now there is only one element for all slides, switching the source instead of the elements, the animation doesn't fire anymore. I tried a lot of things, but with no success.

```
/* FADE */
.slide {-webkit-animation-name:fade; -webkit-animation-duration:1.5s; animation-name:fade; animation-duration:1.5s;}
@-webkit-keyframes fade {from {opacity:.4} to {opacity:1}}
@keyframes fade {from {opacity:.4} to {opacity:1}}
```

So I had to move that animation to JS, using *jQuery*:

```
$(".slide").fadeTo(0,.4,function(){$(this).fadeTo(1500,1);});
```

If you really want to do the animation with CSS, you could use similar code as I used to create the *bullets/dots* (see code snippet), to also create an `<li>` for every slide in the array. But that will crowd your webpage with a whole lot of elements the more slides you add... not sure which option is better.

---

***Code Snippet:***

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var interval;
  var slides = [
    1,
    {txt:"alicè", img:"http://digitaljournal.com/img/8/7/8/4/4/i/1/1/7/o/ulingan_kids.jpg"},
    {txt:"halo halo", img:"http://freethoughtblogs.com/taslima/files/2012/06/22-funny2.jpg"},
    {txt:"tilt", img:"http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png"},
    {txt:"artist unknown", img:"http://www.chinadaily.com.cn/china/images/2010WenUN/attachement/jpg/site1/20100921/0013729ece6b0e01d9691a.jpg"},
    {txt:"insa", img:"http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz2.png"},
    {txt:"blue lights", img:"http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz3.png"},
    {txt:"outdoor festival", img:"http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz3.png"}
  ];
  
  /* SLIDE INTERVAL*/
  function startSlideInterval(){interval = setInterval(function(){$(".next").click();},5000);} //trigger the next-button on every interval
  $('.slide').hover(function(){clearInterval(interval);},startSlideInterval); //clear interval on 'hover', restart interval on 'unhover'
  
  /* SHOW SLIDE */
  function showSlide(n) {
    if (n>slides.length-1) {n=1;} else if (n<1) {n=slides.length-1;} //loop around to first/last slide
    $(".slide img").attr("src",slides[n].img); //change image
    $(".slide div").html(slides[n].txt); //change text
    $(".bullets span:nth-child("+slides[0]+")").removeClass("active"); //deactivate old bullet
    $(".bullets span:nth-child("+n+")").addClass("active"); //activate new bullet
    $(".slide").fadeTo(0,.4,function(){$(this).fadeTo(1500,1);}); //fade new slide
    slides[0] = n; //set slide-index to new value
  }
  
  /* ARROWS */
  $(".prev").click(function(){showSlide(slides[0]-1);}); //click-handler
  $(".next").click(function(){showSlide(slides[0]+1);}); //click-handler
  
  /* BULLETS */
  (function(){
    var bullets = "";
    for (var i=1,count=slides.length; i<count; ++i) {bullets += "<span></span>"} //add a bullet for every slide in the array
    $(".bullets").append(bullets); //append bullets to their container
    $(".bullets span").click(function(){showSlide($(this).index()+1);}); //click-handler
  })();
  
  /* INITIALIZE */
  showSlide(slides[0]); //show the first slide
  startSlideInterval(); //start slide-interval
});
```

```css
html {width:95%; height:90%;} /*ONLY FOR CODE SNIPPET*/
body {width:100%; height:100%;}

/* SLIDER */
#slider {position:relative; width:90%; height:80%; margin:0 auto; background-color:grey; overflow:hidden;}
#slider .slide {width:100%; height:100%; text-align:center;}
#slider .slide img {width:auto; height:100%;}
#slider .slide div {position:absolute; left:0; top:0; margin:0; padding:20px 0 0 25px; text-align:center; font-family:'Montserrat',sans-serif; font-size:40px; font-weight:600; color:#f7f7f7;}

/* ARROWS */
#slider a {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: auto;
  padding: 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}
#slider a:hover {background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);}
#slider a.prev {left:0; border-radius:0 3px 3px 0;}
#slider a.next {right:0; border-radius:3px 0 0 3px;}

/* BULLETS */
.bullets {position:absolute; bottom:10px; width:100%; text-align:center; z-index:1;}
.bullets span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #eee;
  cursor:pointer;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}
.bullets span:hover, .bullets span.active {background-color:#717171;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="slider">
  <div class="slide"><img src="" /><div></div></div>
  <a class="prev">&#10094;</a><a class="next">&#10095;</a>
  <div class="bullets"></div>
</div>
```

**jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hctxgqhx/16/**

Comment: Wow, you're a magician :D Thank you very much, as you could understand I'm very new with javascript and jquery, so I stick codes and codes together trying to make things work :D Thank you!
The only thing I don't get is this 

$(".bullets span:nth-child("+slides[0]+")").removeClass("active"); 
$(".bullets span:nth-child("+n+")").addClass("active");

What means span:nth-child("+slides[0]+") and span:nth-child("+n+")? @myfunkyside

Comment: The first one replaces your for-loop inside `showSlides()` where you do this: `dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace("active", "");`. Where you loop over all the bullets/dots and remove the `"active"` class, I only remove the class from the bullet that we know has the class; the one that corresponds with the active slide. What [**nth-child()**](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) does (see link) is, from all elements matching the *selector* (`".bullets span"`), it selects the element at the `nth` position/index inside the parent container. Read the link and you'll understand..

Comment: And as the number to select that `nth` child, I use the slide-index that is stored in the slide-[**array**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array): `slides[0]` (see link to understand arrays). **IMPORTANT**: arrays start counting at index `[0]`, while `nth-child()` starts at `(1)`. Normally, we'd have to correct for that, but because in our array the slide-index is stored at `[0]`, the real values (the slides) start at index `[1]`, so the slides in the array have the same index as the `nth-child()` number of the bullets on the page..

Comment: `$(".bullets span")` is the jQuery selector to select all the bullets btw: `.bullets` selects all elements (in this case one) with class *"bullets"*, and then the `" span"` (including the space) selects all *span-elements* inside that element. Since your bullets are all *span-elements*, that will select all the bullets..

Comment: So, let's say the current slide is at index `[3]` in the array, and the third bullet is also active (blue), corresponding with the slide. This means that the slide-index number at index `[0]` in the slide-array also has value `3` (you can use `console.log(slides[0]);` to check, use *console.log()* anytime you want to check/debug). Now, `$(".bullets span:nth-child("+slides[0]+")")` - if you write it with the actual value instead of the variable - will simply translate to `$(".bullets span:nth-child(3)")`, so, the third span (bullet). *(In JS, `+` is also used to concatenate strings together.)*

Comment: The same principle is used for the next line: `$(".bullets span:nth-child("+n+")").addClass("active");`, but instead of `slides[0]` we now use `n`, the value that was send along as an argument/parameter when the function was invoked. For instance, by `$(".next").click(function(){showSlide(slides[0]+1);});`, where `n` will have the value of `slides[0]+1`. So, in our previous example that would be `3+1`, is `4`, so the fourth span (bullet) would get class `"active"`. And in CSS the styling for that selector is defined: `.bullets span.active {background-color:#717171;}`, giving it its blue color.

Comment: And at the very end of the function, `slides[0] = n;` sets the slide-index number (at index `[0]` in the slide-array) to `n`, the value of the new slide and active span (bullet). So the next time the function is invoked, `slides[0]` will have this new value... and that's it. Hope this helps, if you still don't fully get it, just ask on, it's usually one tiny detail that holds the key to suddenly opening your eyes.

Comment: That function that is wrapped in parentheses is called an [**IIFE**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) btw, they cause the function to be executed without having to invoke it. Check the links from this link to understand what it does. @BeatriceEffy

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH! @myfunkyside